# Trazer a ultima data de acordo com codigo digitado!

Tags: microsoft-excel, data

Estou com uma planilha onde trago o codigo do cliente  e uma data de visita, gostaria de uma formula onde através do codigo eu traga a ultima data exemplo
Cod.  Data da Visita
1     01/04/2018
2     01/04/2018
3     01/04/2018
1     06/04/2018

retorne
1    06/04/2018
2    01/04/2018
3    01/04/2018

Obrigado

Comment: Você já tentou alguma coisa? Faça o [tour] para saber como funciona a **comunidade**.

Comment: Poderia nos dar mais informações, como um print da tabela para que possamos verificar em quais celulas e colunas estão as informações, e você gostaria dessa solução em fórmula do Excel ou VBA ?